# Best way to create a test database and load fixtures on Symfony 2 WebTestCase?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, tdd

I have a WebTestCase that executes some basic routes in my application.

I want to, on the `setUp` method of PHPUnit, create a test database identical to my main database, and load fixtures into it.

I'm currently doing some workaround and executing some console commands, something like this:

```
class FixturesWebTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    protected static $application;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::runCommand('doctrine:database:create');
        self::runCommand('doctrine:schema:update --force');
        self::runCommand('doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate');
    }

    protected static function runCommand($command)
    {
        $command = sprintf('%s --quiet', $command);

        return self::getApplication()->run(new StringInput($command));
    }

    protected static function getApplication()
    {
        if (null === self::$application) {
            $client = static::createClient();

            self::$application = new Application($client->getKernel());
            self::$application->setAutoExit(false);
        }

        return self::$application;
    }
}
```

But I'm quite sure this is not the best approach, especially because the `doctrine:fixtures:load` expects the user to hit a `Y` char to confirm the action.

How can I solve that?

Comment: See also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091772/how-can-i-load-fixtures-from-functional-test-in-symfony-2/22923295#22923295

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to use `doctrine:fixtures:load`, you can use the `--append` option to avoid the user confirmation. Since you are recreating the database every time, purging is unnecessary. I used to use doctrine fixtures alone for testing, but have since switched to using fixtures & [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle) to avoid DRY. This bundle makes fixtures easier to manage.

EDIT: David Jacquel's answer is the correct one for loading Doctrine Fixtures:

```
doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction 
or
doctrine:fixtures:load -n
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and reference for the `LiipFunctionalTestBundle`!

Comment: One cool thing about LiipFunctionalTestBundle is that you can use a custom test database like Rails does too: https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle#sqlite

Comment: But there is also a discussion about "the new bundle in town": https://github.com/instaclick/ICBaseTestBundle/issues/24

Comment: "new bundle in town" seems a bit overstated.  That issue is 2 years old, and the bundle itself hasn't been updated in 10 months.  Not that Liip has been updated recently either.

Answer (score 36):

In order to bypass user confirmation you can use

```
doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction
or
doctrine:fixtures:load -n
```

Comment: actually this is the best answer, since the right way to do it.

Answer (score 35):

### **UPDATED ANSWER**

You can create a base class for your test cases which makes fixture loading easy by leveraging some classes from the [Doctrine Data Fixtures](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures) library. This class would look pretty much like this:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataFixtures\ContainerAwareLoader;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

abstract class FixtureAwareTestCase extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var ORMExecutor
     */
    private $fixtureExecutor;

    /**
     * @var ContainerAwareLoader
     */
    private $fixtureLoader;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new fixture to be loaded.
     *
     * @param FixtureInterface $fixture
     */
    protected function addFixture(FixtureInterface $fixture)
    {
        $this->getFixtureLoader()->addFixture($fixture);
    }

    /**
     * Executes all the fixtures that have been loaded so far.
     */
    protected function executeFixtures()
    {
        $this->getFixtureExecutor()->execute($this->getFixtureLoader()->getFixtures());
    }

    /**
     * @return ORMExecutor
     */
    private function getFixtureExecutor()
    {
        if (!$this->fixtureExecutor) {
            /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager */
            $entityManager = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
            $this->fixtureExecutor = new ORMExecutor($entityManager, new ORMPurger($entityManager));
        }
        return $this->fixtureExecutor;
    }

    /**
     * @return ContainerAwareLoader
     */
    private function getFixtureLoader()
    {
        if (!$this->fixtureLoader) {
            $this->fixtureLoader = new ContainerAwareLoader(self::$kernel->getContainer());
        }
        return $this->fixtureLoader;
    }
}
```

Then, in your test case, simply extend the above class and before your test add all the needed fixtures and execute them. This will automatically purge your database before loading fixtures. Example follows:

```
class MyTestCase extends FixtureAwareTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // Base fixture for all tests
        $this->addFixture(new FirstFixture());
        $this->addFixture(new SecondFixture());
        $this->executeFixtures();

        // Fixtures are now loaded in a clean DB. Yay!
    }
}
```

### **OLD ANSWER**

*(I decided to "deprecate" this answer because it only explains how to clean up the database without telling how to load fixtures after).*

There's an even cleaner way of accomplishing this without having to run commands. It basically consists in using a combination of the SchemaTool and the ORMPurger. You can create an abstract base class which performs this kind of operations to avoid repeating them for each specialized test case. Here's a code example of a test case class which sets up database for a generic test case:

```
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;

abstract class DatabaseAwareWebTestCase extends WebTestCase {

    public static function setUpBeforeClass() {

        parent::setUpBeforeClass();

        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();
        $em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($em);
        $metadata = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();

        // Drop and recreate tables for all entities
        $schemaTool->dropSchema($metadata);
        $schemaTool->createSchema($metadata);
    }

    protected function tearDown() {

        parent::tearDown();

        $purger = new ORMPurger($this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager());
        $purger->setPurgeMode(ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_TRUNCATE);
        $purger->purge();
    }
}
```

This way, before running each test case which inherits from the above class, the database schema will be rebuilt from scratch, then cleaned up after every test run.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer! However I would suggest to use a trait instead of a class :)

Comment: @lazel sounds like laravel ;)

Comment: it's recommended to not purge your database in the tearDown method, if your test fail, you can still look in your database and check what went wrong

Answer (score 6):

I've stumbled upon a really neat bundle named [Doctrine-Test-Bundle](https://github.com/dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle)
Instead of creating and dropping schema on every test it simply rollback. 
My Tests went from 1m40s to.. 2s. And it's isolated.
All you need is a clear test database and it'll do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I used this command:

```
yes | php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate
```

But of course LiipFunctionalTestBundle looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to load all your fixtures like the `doctrine:fixtures:load` command does. I didn't want to run `exec` from inside the test case because it seemed like a messy way to do things. I looked at how the doctrine command does this itself and just copied over the relevant lines.

I extended from the Symfony `WebTestCase` and after the Kernel was created I just called my method which works exactly like the Doctrine load-fixtures command.

```
    /**
     * Load fixtures for all bundles
     *
     * @param Kernel $kernel
     */
    private static function loadFixtures(Kernel $kernel)
    {
        $loader = new DataFixturesLoader($kernel->getContainer());
        $em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

        foreach ($kernel->getBundles() as $bundle) {
            $path = $bundle->getPath().'/DataFixtures/ORM';

            if (is_dir($path)) {
                $loader->loadFromDirectory($path);
            }
        }

        $fixtures = $loader->getFixtures();
        if (!$fixtures) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Could not find any fixtures to load in');
        }
        $purger = new ORMPurger($em);
        $executor = new ORMExecutor($em, $purger);
        $executor->execute($fixtures, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just recently the bundle [hautelook/AliceBundle](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle) expose two traits to help you solve the use case of loading fixtures in functional tests: `RefreshDatabaseTrait` and `ReloadDatabaseTrait`.

From the doc:

```php
namespace App\Tests;

use Hautelook\AliceBundle\PhpUnit\RefreshDatabaseTrait;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class NewsTest extends WebTestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabaseTrait;

    public function postCommentTest()
    {
        $client = static::createClient(); // The transaction starts just after the boot of the Symfony kernel
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/my-news');
        $form = $crawler->filter('#post-comment')->form(['new-comment' => 'Symfony is so cool!']);
        $client->submit($form);
        // At the end of this test, the transaction will be rolled back (even if the test fails)
    }
}
```

And you are good !