# How can I load fixtures from functional test in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, functional-testing, fixture

My DoctrineFixturesBundle is installed and I can load fixture trough the command-line but , how can I load fixtures from my functional test ?

Comment: did my answer resolve your question? either load the fixtures in the setUp() method as in the question i hinted to or use the LiipFunctionalTestBundle.

Comment: @nifr Thanks it fit my needs, I used the solution in the question you hinted... I will consider the benefits of the LiipFunctionalTestBundle...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can load the fixtures in your test's `setUp()` method as you can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752930/best-way-to-create-a-test-database-and-load-fixtures-on-symfony-2-webtestcase?rq=1).

You can use the code in the question but need to append `--append`to the `doctrine:fixtures:load` command in order to avoid the confirmation by the fixtures-bundle.

The better solution is to have a look at the [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle) which makes using data-fixtures easier.

Answer (score 27):

If you use symfony's `WebTestCase`, there's actually a very easy way to load your fixtures.
Your fixture has to implement the `FixtureInterface`; thus, you can call it's `load()` method directly in your test's `setUp()` method. You just have to pass an `EntityManager` to the `load()` method, which can be aquired from the symfony container:

```
public function setUp() {
    $client = static::createClient();
    $container = $client->getContainer();
    $doctrine = $container->get('doctrine');
    $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();

    $fixture = new YourFixture();
    $fixture->load($entityManager);
}
```

Comment: This misses all ReferenceRepository stuff - addRef/getRef

Comment: Do not forget to add reference repository before the load call. `$fixture->setReferenceRepository(new ReferenceRepository($entityManager));`

Answer (score 13):

I just wanted to offer a slightly neater approach if you want to first purge your table of previous test data, e.g. if you are running your tests in phpunit.

```
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader;
use Namespace\FakeBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\YourFixtures;

public function setUp()
{
    static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
    static::$kernel->boot();
    $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
        ->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager()
    ;

    $loader = new Loader();
    $loader->addFixture(new YourFixtures);

    $purger = new ORMPurger($this->em);
    $executor = new ORMExecutor($this->em, $purger);
    $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());

    parent::setUp();
}
```

This allows fixtures to be loaded, (you can push more into the add fixture method), and purge the tables before they are loaded. 
Also note MongoDB has the same option using MongoDBPurger, and MongoDBExecutor.
Hope it helps someone

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use your approach but `$executor` intent to delete the whole database and not just the related tables, why is that behavior? Any example in how to purge the generated data during fixtures load?

Answer (score 2):

As it was already mentioned it's recommended to use the *LiipFunctionalTestBundle*. 
Then you want extend your `WebTestCase` from the `Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase`. This will allow to call `$this->loadFixtures()` which takes an array of fixtures as an argument.

```
$fixtures = array('Acme\MemeberBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadMemberData');
$this->loadFixtures($fixtures);
```

For more details I wrote a short [blogpost](http://marcjuch.li/blog/2014/04/06/symfony2-rest-functional-testing-with-fixtures/).