# Loading Fixtures for functional tests in Symfony 2: Call to undefined method MyControllerTest::loadFixtures())

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, functional-testing, fixtures

I am trying to find the easy way to load my fixtures in Symfony 2.6 to run functional tests. This is a quite common question, and has been asked a few times, but the answers I have found so far do not quite reach my expectations:

- [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752930/best-way-to-create-a-test-database-and-load-fixtures-on-symfony-2-webtestcase?rq=1) rely on running the command line from inside the functional test.
- [Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20400624/1686492) run manually each one of the defined fixtures, and then take care of creating and deleting the database.

There is a lot of overhead in both cases (use statements and manual code), for a task that I believe is very standard.

On the other hand, these same posts recommend the LiipFunctionalTestBundle. Going for it, here is what I read in the installation instructions:

> write fixture classes and call loadFixtures() method from the bundled
>   Test\WebTestCase class. Please note that loadFixtures() will delete the contents from the database before loading the fixtures."

So I tried...

```
namespace AppBundle\Test\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class MyControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $classes = array(
                'AppBundle\DataFixtures\LoadUserData',
        );
        $this->loadFixtures($classes);
    }
    ...
}
```

With no luck:

> Call to undefined method AppBundle\Tests\Controller\MyControllerTest::loadFixtures() in /gitrepos/myproject/src/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/MyControllerTest.php on line 15

a static call gives the same error...

```
self:loadFixtures($classes);
```

I really think I am missing something pretty obvious. Anyone can get me back on track ?

Comment: `LiipFunctionalTestBundle`  expects `setup()` to include an array `$classes = array(...)` of fixtures and then `$this->loadFixtures($classes);` Your setup shows no classes and `loadFixtures()` is devoid of any class array.

Comment: @geoB the error message suggests this is not the issue. I updated the post though, to avoid confusion. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @dragoste I do not see any mention of the loadFixtures function in this post. Furthermore, it is 2 years old, and it seems these bundles have been quite updated since. I do believe there is a much better way to do this today.

Comment: @mika sorry, didn't read your question carefully. I can see you're using `Oro\Bundle\TestFrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase` as the base class while I think you should use `Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase` to be able to call this method.

Comment: @dragoste Oh yes... I was myself going through the Liip installation instructions too fast: I was using   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase; which does not have the loadFixtures function. If you make your comment an answer, that will be the correct one. Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you're using

```
Oro\Bundle\TestFrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase
```

as the base class while I think you should use

```
Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase
```

to be able to call this method.