# Calling Command from within a WebTestCase

Tags: symfony

I am trying to call 'router:debug' Command from within a WebTestCase to validate all static routes automatically.

```
class RoutesTest extends WebTestCase
{
  public function setUp() 
   {
     $command = self::getApplication()->find('router:debug');
     $input = new ArrayInput(array());
     $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);
     if($returnCode == 0) {
        var_dump($output);
     }
   }
}
```

But I get a

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MyApplication\MyBundle\Tests\Controller\RoutesTest::getApplication() in /data/www/symfony/src/Prexem/UserBundle/Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php

Answer (score 0):

I thought that self::getApplication() was a member of WebTestCase because I saw snipplet with this method.

But actually I have to implement it like in this one:
[Best way to create a test database and load fixtures on Symfony 2 WebTestCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752930/best-way-to-create-a-test-database-and-load-fixtures-on-symfony-2-webtestcase)