# How to append fixtures in liip functional test (symfony 2.8)?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing, liipfunctionaltestbundle

I would like to append fixtures in my functional test (based on  [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle) in symfony 2.8. Even it is a dev database I working on, I do still need to append the fixtures since I will have:

- regional data (country, region, county)
- vehicule brands and models
- ...

Consequently, having the DB purged after each functional test will not be nice for me.

**NOTICE:** Appending fixtures (without purging) through command line is working with success: `php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append`

So, below is my functional test:

```
<?php

namespace Minn\APIBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase as WebTestCase;
//use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase as WebTestCase;
use Minn\APIBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Entity\LoadBrandData;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;

class BrandControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

    public function setUp() {
        $this->auth = array(
            'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'restapi',
            'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'secretpw',
        );

        $this->client = static::createClient(array(), $this->auth);
    }

    public function testJsonGetPageAction() {
        $fixtures = array('Minn\APIBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Entity\LoadBrandData');
        $this->loadFixtures($fixtures);
        $brands = LoadBrandData::$brands;
        $brand = array_pop($brands);

        $route = $this->getUrl('api_1_brand_get_brand', array('id' => $brand->getId(), '_format' => 'json'));

        $this->client->request('GET', $route, array('ACCEPT' => 'application/json'));
        $response = $this->client->getResponse();
        $this->assertJsonResponse($response, 200);
        $content = $response->getContent();

        $decoded = json_decode($content, true);
        $this->assertTrue(isset($decoded['id']));
    }

    // ..
}
```

This test purges the DB. So, I tried the code proposed in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752930/best-way-to-create-a-test-database-and-load-fixtures-on-symfony-2-webtestcase?rq=1) by doing this change:

```
// removed code
$fixtures = array('Minn\APIBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Entity\LoadBrandData');
$this->loadFixtures($fixtures);

// new code
$this->runCommand('doctrine:fixtures:load --append --no-interaction --fixtures=src/Minn/APIBundle/Tests/Fixtures/Entity/LoadBrandData.php');
```

But, functional test doest not work.

```
There was 1 error:

1) Minn\APIBundle\Tests\Controller\BrandControllerTest::testJsonGetPageAction
Error: Call to a member function getId() on null

/home/amine/NetBeansProjects/minnapi/src/Minn/APIBundle/Tests/Controller/BrandControllerTest.php:27
```

I tried to used options available in the function *loadFixtures()* by doing this change:

```
// removed code:
$fixtures = array('Minn\APIBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Entity\LoadBrandData');
$this->loadFixtures($fixtures);

// new code 
$fixtures = array('Minn\APIBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Entity\LoadBrandData');
$this->loadFixtures($fixtures, null,'doctrine', ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_DELETE);
```

Verdict: DB is always purged after each run of the functional test.

So, any suggestions??

Thanks,

**NB:** bundles versions described in composer.json

```
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.4.*",
    "liip/functional-test-bundle":"1.6.*",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "v3.9.*"
```

Comment: Is there some reason for not using a separate database for functional testing as would otherwise be expected?

Comment: I am open to all ideas. You have a link or an example ?

Comment: Do you use the SQLite database as described in the bundle's configuration?

Comment: I use mysql. That's it. No sqlite

Comment: If for some reason SQLite is not an option (for example, when you use a MySQL function that is not available in SQLite) you can always define a separate MySQL database for the test environment.  As for appending fixtures, use `...DataFixtures\ORM` for your dev environment, `..DataFixtures\Test` for the test environment.

Comment: Can you be more explicite @geoB regarding the dev environment and test environment?

Comment: You comment is right! I do use geospatial queries and I guess they will not work in SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution to avoid having the database purged is to create a testing database. To do that, below are the steps:

## config of a testing database

```
# the config has to be done in config_test.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   test
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
```

## creation of the database and the tables

```
// this command is run only once (just for creating the testing db)
$ php app/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
// this command is needed when you have new entities
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:create --env=test
```

## How to load fixtures in the test?

```
    $fixtures = array('Minn\APIBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Entity\LoadBrandData');
    $this->loadFixtures($fixtures);
    $brands = LoadBrandData::$brands;
```

Hope it will help others!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a SQLite database for functional testing.  See [the docs](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/blob/master/README.md#database-tests) for details on the bundle's configuration.  If, for example, you are using MySQL it is pretty straightforward to create a database in the test environment with

```
$ php app/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:create --env=test
```

and have the same behavior in the test environment as in the dev environment.

Your fixtures should load readily.

Edit:
in config_test.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     localhost
        port:     3306
        dbname:   minnapi_test
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
```

Copy `.../web/app_dev.php` to `.../web/app_test.php` and modify one line to read `$kernel = new AppKernel('test', true);`

Comment: I can not your use your solution since the database already exists in mySQL: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1007 Can't create database 'minnapi'; database exists`